# .Net Core Receive FileContentResult from one API to Another

Tags: .net, httpresponsemessage, filecontentresult

I am having trouble finding information on how to do this so I will ask here.

The situation is that I have an API that has a response type of FileContentResult. I have another API that needs to receive this FileContentResult. So, I guess the real question is, how do I convert a HttpResponseMessage to FileContentResult? I am using System.Net.Http.HttpClient to send the request to the API that returns the FileContentResult. Thanks