# How can I consume a FileContentResult returned from an .Net Core api inside a .Net WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net-core, filecontentresult

I am trying something similar posted [here][1]

[1]: [.Net Core Receive FileContentResult from one API to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712458/net-core-receive-filecontentresult-from-one-api-to-another)   This is what I am trying and I think I am very close,just that not sure how to receive the in the receiver Api a response which is being sent by the Producer Api as FileContentResult, any help will be appreciated.
My effort is listed below:
//Source API-working well

```
[HttpPost("download")]
        public async Task<FileContentResult> ExportApplicationUsers2(ExportApplicationUsersQuery command)
        {
            try
            {
               var filePath = await Mediator.Send(command);
                return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), "application/octet-stream");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    throw ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
```

---

```
    //Controller in Consumer Api
public async Task<Result<FileContentResult>> ExportApplicationUsers(ExportUsersRequest model)
        {
            try
            {
                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                var response = await httpClient.PostFileAsync("/users/download", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
                return response;
                //return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(response), "application/octet-stream");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                return new Result<FileContentResult>(new List<string> { ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

The Actual PostFileAsync() which I need to fix first:

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> PostFileAsync(string uri, object data)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

        if (data != null)
        {
            request.Content = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        }

        var response = default(FileContentResult);
        var actionTask = _httpClient.SendAsync(request)
              .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
              {
                  FileStreamResult resposneMessage = responseTask.Result;
                  response = (FileContentResult)resposneMessage.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;//This is where I need help as its not able to convert into FileContentResult!
              });
        actionTask.Wait();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: `responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);`  `return File(await responseMessage.ReadAsStreamAsync());`.